# Width auto and scrollbar causing linebreak

Tags: html, css

Community,

at the moment I struggle with an annoying problem.
On our website we have a calendar where dates are differently colored depending on what event is on that day.
There's a legend to tell which color is which event.

To make things better for mobile users I implemented a floating button with which an overlay for the legend can be toggled. This also works without problems, there's just this one thing that's bugging me.

The width of the container is set to *auto*, so that when new, longer texts for events are added the width doesn't have to be edited manually. In Firefox and Safari the longest text(s) will break below the colored div, as soon as the scrollbar is necessary to show up, due to overflow..

[Firefox v65.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4Gh2.png)

In Chrome and even in IE/Edge it works correctly, the scrollbar is taken into account and *width: auto* makes the div as wide as necessary.

[Chrome v72.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pN9r8.png)

Is this a browser problem, or is it somehow possible to fix it without manually setting a width ?

The Code to recreate it:

```css
#container {
  width: auto;
  max-height: 75vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow: auto;
  float: right;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 15px;
  right: calc(30px + 10vw);
  max-width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.second {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}

.legende {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 3px;
  background: #3388aa;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="legende">

    </div>
    <div class="second">
      Some Text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="legende">

    </div>
    <div class="second">
      Some longer Text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="legende">

    </div>
    <div class="second">
      Some more Text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="legende">

    </div>
    <div class="second">
      Another Text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="legende">

    </div>
    <div class="second">
      Some Text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="legende">

    </div>
    <div class="second">
      Some longer Text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="legende">

    </div>
    <div class="second">
      Some more Text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="legende">

    </div>
    <div class="second">
      Another Text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont see any issue on Firefox 65.0.1 on mac
https://i.imgur.com/RvOXdHa.png

Comment: weird.. I'm on Linux Mint 19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more try! I added an .inner div to keep the fixed position separate.

```css
#container {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 15px;
 right: calc(30px + 10vw);
}

.inner {
 width: 120%;
  max-height: 75vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.wrapper {
 margin: 5px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.second {
 float: left;
 margin: 5px;
}

.legende {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 margin: 3px;
 background: #3388aa;
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div class="inner">
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="legende">

   </div>
   <div class="second">
    Some Text
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="legende">

   </div>
   <div class="second">
    Some longer Text
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="legende">

   </div>
   <div class="second">
    Some more Text
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="legende">

   </div>
   <div class="second">
    Another Text
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="legende">

   </div>
   <div class="second">
    Some Text
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="legende">

   </div>
   <div class="second">
    Some longer Text
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="legende">

   </div>
   <div class="second">
    Some more Text
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="legende">

   </div>
   <div class="second">
    Another Text
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, thanks!
This seems to work on all browsers I've tested so far, for me the perfect solution!

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox instead of float:

```css
#container {
  width: auto;
  max-height: 75vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow: auto;
  float: right;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 15px;
  right: calc(30px + 10vw);
  max-width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  margin: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.second {
  margin: 5px;
}

.legende {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 3px;
  background: #3388aa;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="legende">

    </div>
    <div class="second">
      Some Text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="legende">

    </div>
    <div class="second">
      Some longer Text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="legende">

    </div>
    <div class="second">
      Some more Text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="legende">

    </div>
    <div class="second">
      Another Text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="legende">

    </div>
    <div class="second">
      Some Text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="legende">

    </div>
    <div class="second">
      Some longer Text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="legende">

    </div>
    <div class="second">
      Some more Text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="legende">

    </div>
    <div class="second">
      Another Text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this seems to be fixing the problem with the linebreaks, but the Scrollbar should be only visible if it's necessary, which on a mobile device in portrait-mode is rarely the case (at least for now..)

Comment: Hmm.. If there's nothing else to fix it, I would definitely use this approach, even though I find it visually not too appealing since the rows aren't of equal height..
I just don't get why it's breaking when it could technically fill all the space it has, since max-width is set to 100% ..

Answer (score 0):

Even if i don't see the issue on firefox 65.0.1 adn Safari on mac, you can disable the elements wrapping by adding `white-space: nowrap;` to the `.wapper` element.

```
.wrapper {
  margin: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Tried that, but for me it's not fixing the problem..
Firefox 65.0 on Linx Mint 19 or Safari 11.1.2 on Mac High Sierra (10.13.6) both break the texts below the colored div, as soon as the scrollbar shows up
[Safari 11.1.2](https://imgur.com/a/liMTx5a)

Comment: I think your issue is related to the not-overlay scrollbars. I think you should try adding absolute to the list with coordinates at 0

Comment: _position: absolute_  on the .wrapper class?
This makes the whole thing disappear..

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved using a CSS property:

```
scrollbar-gutter: stable;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-gutter

In addition, you can significantly reduce the code and simplify the implementation of your idea.

```css
#container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 15px;
  right: calc(30px + 10vw);
  max-height: 75vh; 
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); 
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  scrollbar-gutter: stable;
}
#container > div {
  margin: 10px 0 10px 10px;
  border-left: 30px solid #3388aa;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>Some Text</div>
  <div>Some longer Text</div>
  <div>Some more Text</div>
  <div>Another Text</div>
  <div>Some Text</div>
  <div>Some longer Text</div>
  <div>Some more Text</div>
  <div>Another Text</div> 
</div>
```